# Getting a compile error when I save a template file that disappears when I save a different template

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to use a checkbox component from ngx bootstrap. I am using this component in a parent template but get a compile error when I save the checkbox template. However, when I save the parent template, the app is able to compile and I don't get any errors. I can repeat this over and over, where saving the child shows a compile error and saving the parent compiles without any issues. When compiled, the functionality works as intended.

Why is my app doing this? And why and I getting the compile error in the first place? The component looks right and is copied letter for letter from the ngx bootstrap resources.

Checkbox Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-custom-checkbox-value',
  templateUrl: './custom-checkbox-value.html'
})
export class DemoButtonsCustomCheckboxValueComponent {
  singleModel = '1';
}
```

Checkbox Template

```
<pre class="card card-block card-header">{{singleModel}}</pre>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        [(ngModel)]="singleModel" btnCheckbox
        btnCheckboxTrue="1" btnCheckboxFalse="0">
  Single Toggle
</button>
{{singleModel}}
```

Parent Template

```
<demo-custom-checkbox-value>
```

Error when saving the Checkbox template. The error points to the btnCheckboxTrue and btnCheckboxFalse in the component template

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Edit: The compile error seems to arise when I save any of the files in Visual Studio, which seems to recompile the app. The only file that I can save that allows errorless compilation is the parent template. Even when I save app.module I get the compilation error.

Comment: does the error go away if you remove `btnCheckboxTrue="1" btnCheckboxFalse="0"` from the template?

Comment: @BizzyBob yes it does but then I lose some functionality with the checkbox itself. When I can get it working by saving the parent component last, I can for example set btnCheckBoxTrue="On" and btnCheckboxFalse="Off" and it changes the singleModel variable in my class. However, it needs to be able to compile by saving the parent template file for this to work. The checkbox component itself can be found [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/buttons#custom-checkbox-value) and the stackblitz example works without any issues which makes me things there's something wrong with my compiler

Comment: Managed to avoid the error completely by downgrading to Angular 10, which is the last supported version by ngx bootstrap. What this doesn't answer however is why I was able to get the project to compile if I saved a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just hold a boolean in your component.ts and use a ternary operator in you template if you want to use Angular 11 / 12 ...

Although using libraries that support your version of Angular or vice versa is not a bad idea.

Component.ts:

```js
singleModel = false
```

Template:

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary"
  name="singleModel"
  [(ngModel)]="singleModel"
  btnCheckbox
>
  {{ singleModel ? "On" : "Off" }}
</button>
```